# How can I fill up a form field from views.py in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am using a function to record the time between which the page is loaded and the user submits the data. In that form, I have created a hidden field so that the admin can see it. However, I am unable to implement my idea since I don't understand how I can submit the time to the form from views.py. If someone can suggest an easier and simpler alternative methods to achieve what I am trying to do, that would be very helpful to me as well.  My code is as follows.

**models.py**

```
class Responses(models.Model):
    question1 = models.TextField()
    question2 = models.TextField()
    question3 = models.TextField()
    timespent1 = models.TextField()
```

**forms.py**

```
class Question1Form(forms.ModelForm):
question1 = forms.CharField()
timespent1 = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

class Meta:
    model = Responses
    fields = ('question1','timespent1')
```

**views.py**

```
def qone(request):
if request.method =="GET":
    starttime = my_timer()
elif request.method == "POST":
    form = Question1Form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        endtime = my_timer()
        timespentstr = '{0} seconds'.format(endtime-starttime)
        #Do something to set timespent1 field = timespentstr here
        form = form.save()
else:
    form = Question1Form

return render(request,'question1.html',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store the start time "somewhere else" - perhaps store it in the session in the GET, and then pull it back out from there in the POST:

```
def qone(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        request.session['start_time'] = mytimer()
        form = Question1Form()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = Question1Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            end_time = mytimer()
            start_time = request.session.get('start_time')
            time_spent = end_time - start_time
            ....
            form.save()

return render(request, 'question1.html', {'form': form})
```

You could also look at passing in the start time to the form directly, and then having all of the logic in there, but that might complicate things. Perhaps passing the "time taken" to the form constructor might be the best way.

```
class Question1Form(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.time_taken = self.kwargs.pop('time_taken', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


def qone(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = Question1Form()
        request.session['start_time'] = my_timer()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = Question1Form(
            request.POST, request.FILES, 
            time_taken=my_timer() - request.session.pop('start_time')
        )
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    # ...
```

Comment: Okay. This looks a bit complicated since I am a beginner but I think I can work it out. But will this method upload the time spent to the database?